# Decoding the expiry date of a JavaScript Web Token (JWT)?

Tags: ruby-on-rails, jwt

I am unable to understand the expiry date format of the JWT embedded in my application.

For example: 1473912000

What does this translate to? 1473912000 ms, some x date? Any help will be appreciated!

Comment: That's a [Unix timestamp](https://en.m.wikipedia.org/wiki/Unix_time).

Comment: Does this answer your question? [Convert a Unix timestamp to time in JavaScript](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/847185/convert-a-unix-timestamp-to-time-in-javascript)

Answer (score 43):

Like James has pointed out:

> The number is the number of seconds since Jan 1 1970.

This is converted into the `Date` object in a quite straight-forward way (the `*1000` part is here because in JS main time unit is millisecond):

```
const expiryDate = new Date(1473912000*1000);
```

Then you can use any [`Date` method](https://developer.mozilla.org/en/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/Date) you please.

Likewise, in Ruby you can use `Time.at(1473912000)` to [create a new Time instance](https://ruby-doc.org/core-2.7.1/Time.html#class-Time-label-Creating+a+new+Time+instance) like Maxim has shown.

Answer (score 7):

The number is the number of seconds since Jan 1 1970. It is commonly used on unix systems to represent time. Your time is 2016-09-15 04:00 (UTC)

To convert you can try a web based system http://www.unixtimestamp.com/index.php

Answer (score 5):

This is [UNIX time](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Unix_time) in seconds:

```
➜  ~ irb
2.2.0 :001 > Time.at(1473912000)
 => 2016-09-15 07:00:00 +0300
```